# How can I ensure current arrow a little bit far away from voltage source?

Tags: circuitikz

The current arrow is almost overlapped with test voltage here.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,right=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}  % for drawing pictures
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz} % circuit package and  include electrical units in our labels

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}[american, ]
\ctikzset{tripoles/mos style/arrows}

\def\killdepth#1{{\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{#1}}}

\draw 
(-3,9)  -- (3,9) node[label=right: $V_{dd} \SI{}{}$] {}

(2,9) to [resistor, a^ = $R_3$] (2,5)

(2,1) node[nmos] (M1) {$M_1$}
(M1.source) node[] {} to (2,0) node[ground](GND){} (2,-3)



(2,5) -- (-3,5) to [resistor, a^ = $R_2$] (-3,1)
 to [resistor, a^ = $R_1$] (-3,-1.5)
 -- (-3,-1.5) node[ground](GND){} (-3,-2)



(2,4)node[nmos] (M2) {$M_2$}
(0,4) node[anchor=east] {$V_{bias}$}[short, o-] to (M2.gate) node[] {}
(M2.source) node[] {} -- (M1.drain) node[] {}
(M2.drain) node[right] {} -- (2,5) to  [short, *-o, name=S] ++ (2,0) node[right]{$V_{out}$};



\draw (5,0) node[ground](GND){}  to (5,0) to [I, i_>=$I_{in}$]  (5,2)[short, -*] to (2,2)[short, *-*];
%\draw  [short, -](5,1) to  [short, *-*, name=S] ++(3,0)node[right]{$V_{out}$};

%\draw  [short, *-] (-2,0) to [resistor, a = $R_2$] (-2,-3);   

\draw (M1.gate) to (0,1)  -- (0,0) to [V=$V_t$,  i<^=$I_{t}$] (0,-1)
to (0,-2) node[ground](GND){};    
 
\end{circuitikz}
\caption{break the loop and add test voltage } \label{fig:test_voltage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The current arrow is almost invisible in voltage source while visible in current source.
How can I make current visible in voltage source (to make it like the current source)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first of all, a suggestion: try to reduce your code here to a *minimal* form to show the problem at hand --- I understand that pasting your whole code is easier for you, but it's *much* harder for people trying to answer. I reduced your code to a minimal example here (and btw, your code does not compile, missing the package for the `H` option to figure).

The problem is that you allow too little space for the generator, so the arrow overlaps. The basic length default in `circuitikz` is 1.4 cm, so a distance of 1 (cm) is too little if you want space in the leads to add currents.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{tripoles/mos style/arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}

    \draw (2,1) node[nmos] (M1) {$M_1$}
    (M1.source) node[] {} to (2,0) node[ground](GND){} (2,-3);

    \draw (M1.gate) to (0,1)  -- (0,0) to [V=$V_t$,  i<^=$I_{t}$] (0,-3)
    node[ground](GND){};

\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]